# Array Manipulation Menu C Programming

Tags: c, menu, switch-statement, case

I have a menu where the user has to enter a number the following case will do manipulation to the array. However the menu has to be done in order. For example the user must first set the size of the array and then pass the elements into the array in a separate module.

1. 1- Enter the size of the array  2- Enter the array elements  3- Sort
   the array  4- Find a number within the array  5- Print the array
   6-Reverse print the array  7- Quit

Please enter your choice: 3
Your array is not initialized yet!

This is my code so far. I am having trouble on initializing my array and entering the elements. Once i get those done i am sure i can do the rest:

```
int sizeArray();
int *enterElements(int size, int *anArray);


int main(){
    int choice; 
    int tempSize;
    int mArray[100]; //initialize the Array
    do{
        printf("1 - Enter the size of the array\n");
        printf("2 - Enter the array elements\n");
        printf("3 - Sort the array\n");
        printf("4 - Find a number within the array\n");
        printf("5 - Print the Array\n");
        printf("6 - Reverse print the array\n");
        printf("7 - Quit\n");
        printf("\n");
        printf("Please Enter your choice: ");
        scanf("%d", &choice);

        switch (choice){
        case 1:
            int tempSize = sizeArray(); 
        case 2: 
            if (tempSize != 0){
                enterElements(tempSize); 
            }
            else{
                printf("You should first set the size of the array\n"); 
            }
        default:
            if (choice < 1 || choice > 7)
                printf("Invalid choice please choose again\n");
        };
    } while (choice != 7);

}

int sizeArray(){
    int size = 0; 
    printf("What is the size of your array(1-20)? "); 
    scanf_s("%d", size); 
    if (size > 20 || size < 1){
        printf("Array size should be between 1 and 20 "); 
    }
    return size; 
}

int *enterElements(int size){
    int i = 0; 
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter Array Element %d :", i);
        scanf_s("%d", &anArray[i]); 
    }
}
```

Comment: `int tempSize = sizeArray();` : remove `int`, add `break;` after this.

Comment: Please don't vandalise your question; the code is relevant to answering this.

Answer (score 0):

I think enterElements function should look like this:

```
void enterElements(int *anArray, int size)
{
 //Your code here
}
```

And call your function as:

```
enterElements(mArray, tempSize);
```

Also within case you shouldn't declare new int tempSize variable, it overrides the one before loop.

Comment: if i initizlied the array outside of the enterElements method aren't i already setting the size of the array?

Comment: When you define array, you set it's size. Precisely you allocate space on stack for it. Remember that in c there is no built-in control of array size. To initialize with some starting values you can do something like that: `int mArray[100]={0};`. This will initialize whole array.

Comment: So if i am initializing the the array in the main method with mArray[100] and then i am setting its size in another module am i changing the size of the array?

Comment: With mArray[100] you define a table, not initialize it. But essentially yes, this where you tell your compiler how big your array is. The moment you set your tempSize variable, you don't change actual array size, but you can use this variable to control access to the array.

Answer (score 0):

You have following mistakes:

1. Remove `int` before using `tempSize` variable in switch statement;
2. In prototype you declared that `enterElements` function takes 2(!) parameters and return a pointer. But in function implementation you have only one parameter and have no return value.

Comment: I realize those mistakes. I just don't know how to initialize the array in order to fill it with elements.

Comment: I just used different func `scanf("%d", &size);` and `scanf("%d", &anArray[i]);`

Comment: I am initializing that array outside of that function however. When i do this am i changing the size of the array?

Comment: No. The size of array sets in this line `int mArray[100];` and automatically initialize with 0.